# Magento - How to diplsay tax/vat percentage in Invoice PDF totals, and also change Tax labels to Vat

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to display the vat percentage in the invoice pdfs. So when the admin is in the back end viewing an invoice and clicks print, they'll see the invoice with 'vat @ %' in the totals. Currently it displays tax as the label so i'd also like to change that to VAT.

So far I've managed to display the vat % for each product in the invoice by adding the following to

```
    app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

      // draw Tax
    $taxPercent = $item->getOrderItem()->getTaxPercent();
    $taxPercent = number_format($taxPercent,2,',','');
    $taxPercent = $taxPercent."%";
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount())." @".$taxPercent ,
        'feed'  => 515,
        'font'  => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right'
    );
```

That's works fine but I'd also like to display it next to 'Tax' in the totals.

I've also tried changing the Tax labels to VAT by editing the following csv files in locale

```
    en_US/Mage_Reports.csv
    en_us/Mage_Tax.csv
```

I also copied both csv files to en_GB but that did bugger all for me as well

There must be an easy way to change the labels and add the vat percentage in the totals?

Thank you for any help

**EDIT** Come to think about it, i dont think its possible to add the tax rate in the totals as each product in the invoice may have a different tax rate. so for now i'm happy listing the tax rate for each product.

Still can't seem to change the tax labels or add a new column to the products table in the invoice, it would be nice to have a "tax rate" column heading next to the tax amount

**EDIT 2** Found out it was an extension overriding the invoice.php file stopping me from changing the column headings for the products table, how annoying!. That's solved that issue, Although the totals still have tax not VAT